# Why won't I append an int array in Java?

Tags: java

I have some simple method for a little simple code challenge here. I was wondering why I seem to be unable to append an int array... I was trying different ways to do that, but to no avail. This is the last thing I've tried, it's giving me [array index is out of bounds] error.

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    int count = 0;
    int[] storage = new int[]{};


    for (int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
        if ((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0)) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(i);
            storage[storage.length-1]=i;
        }
        if (count==5){
            break;
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<storage.length;i++){
        sum+=storage[i];
    }

    System.out.println(sum);

}
```

storage is the int array. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Where in this code do you believe you've written the declaration of your int array as one _with space to put values_?

Comment: Because arrays in Java have a fixed length. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: if you answer your own question in under 5 minutes after posting, please feel free to delete the question again, as you clearly posted it well before [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this declaration allocates an empty array:

```
int[] storage = new int[]{};
```

If you want to initialize an array to a fixed length, you declare it like that:

```
int[] storage = new int[1001];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an array in Java, you have to specify the size of the array. Example:

```
 int[] storage = new int[5];
```

You can then specify the index you want to put the data in.

If you want an array that can dynamically resize, you should use an ArrayList instead

```
List<Integer> storage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And then use

```
storage.add(4);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think I resolved it. I haven't allocated a number of elements to the array on declaration.